# ImageMap with mouseout

Tags: javascript, mouseover, mouseout

hi i asked this once but couldn't get an answer i have this image map of a building see here =>> http://projectpano.netii.net/imagemaper.html and it has 5 hotspots on the building each of them has a onmouseover onmouseout event .. but wat i can't do is make the show in the right even if im mouseout of the hotspot like this one for example http://31pennplaza.com/avail.html#

see the source page of mine and pls help me with the script im new with this !

Comment: So, you want the last "active" plan to stay visible, if user will move mouse out of the picture?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to view your example, so I will make some assumptions.

Your hotspots are likely positioned divs (or some other element) and they should each have  unique DOM IDs.

I believe you want the image on the right to update whenever your mouseOver a new hotspot, and you want that image to remain there until you mouseOver another hotspot. mouseOut events should not affect the image on the right.

Let's say your hotspots are declared like this:

```
<div id="hotspot_1" class="hotspot"></div>
<div id="hotspot_2" class="hotspot"></div>
...
<div id="hotspot_5" class="hotspot"></div>
```

And the image you are updating on the right is:

```
<img id="floor_detail" src="images/floor_detail.jpg" />
```

And the images you want to show when you rollover the hotspots have the following paths:

```
images/hotspot_1_detail.jpg
images/hotspot_2_detail.jpg
...
images/hotspot_5_detail.jpg
```

You can configure the behavior using jQuery. You don't need mouseOut event listeners because it sounds like you want the detail image to retain its state until another mouseOver is observed.

jQuery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hotspot").live("mouseover", function() {
      $("#floor_detail").attr("src", "images/" + $(this).attr("id") + "_detail.jpg");
    });    
  });
</script>
```

Comment: There was a [correct link](http://projectpano.netii.net/imagemaper.html) in OP's previous question, seems to be a typo in the link in this post.

Comment: sorry i edited the link .. gooberverse thnx take a look at my edited link see what i've done

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: remove your onMouseOut handlers. For the behavior you've specified, you don't need them.